# Show all dates even when status is Null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query to display attendance status of employees between two dates.

Two parameters, `@FromDate` and `@ToDate`, are passed into a stored procedure. This stored procedure has a CTE with all the dates between this period filled in. This is represented by T in the below query. Another CTE, namely TUI, holds all dates of T plus all relevant USER IDs coming from another table named `USER_INFO`.

Other tables that need to be joined are:

Table: `USER_INFO`

```
USER_ID INT P.K, DISPLAY_NAME Varchar
```

Table: `ATTDETAILS`

```
inUserID INT P.K, dtAttendanceDate  DateTime, inAttendanceStatusId INT F.K
```

Table: `Att_Status_Master`

```
inAttendanceStatusId INT P.K, ATTStatus VARCHAR
```

The column, `AttStatus` in table `Att_Status_Master` above, holds values: `Present, Absent` etc.

The problem with the below code is that it is giving results only when any of the `AttStatus` exists for a particular date. If none of the employee has marked the attendance on a particular date then that date is not coming in the result set.

I want all the dates to be displayed irrespective of the NULL values. The CTE T mentioned above is providing all the dates between two dates to temporary table #Results. Now I want to show all these dates for all the employees.

For example:

[image]

As you can see above, date 01/dec/2012 has no status, but it should still be displayed in the results. Whereas with the below query, it is not being displayed. The below query is only displaying records where `AttStatus` is filled.

The final stored procedure code is as below:

```
@FromDate   DateTime    /* Input Parameter */
@ToDate     DateTime    /* Input Parameter */

If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results',N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Results

DECLARE @StartDate  DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate    DateTime

@StartDate = Convert(Varchar(25),@FromDate,112)
@EndDate = Convert(Varchar(25), (DateAdd(DAY,15,@FromDate)),112)

;With T (tempStoredDate)
AS (
    select @StartDate
    union all
    select dateadd(day,1,tempStoredDate) from T where T.tempStoredDate < @EndDate
),
TUI AS
(
    select T.tempStoredDate, UI.user_id, ui.display_name, dbo.GetEmployeeCode(UI.user_id) AS EmpCode from T
    cross join user_info UI
)

select TUI.EmpCode, UI.user_id, UI.Display_Name, TUI.tempStoredDate, AD.dtAttendanceDate, ASM.AttStatus
INTO #Results From TUI
left outer join user_info UI
on TUI.user_id = UI.user_id
left outer join Att_Details AD
on UI.user_id = AD.inUserId
inner join Att_Status_Master ASM
on ASM.inAttendanceStatusId = AD.inAttendanceStatusId
where Convert(Varchar(25),dtAttendanceDate,112) = Convert(Varchar(25),tempStoredDate,112)
group by TUI.tempStoredDate,UI.user_id,UI.Display_Name,TUI.EmpCode,AD.dtAttendanceDate,AD.inAttendanceStatusId,ASM.AttStatus
```

I noticed that because of the WHERE clause this is happening. If I ignore the `WHERE` clause, all dates are visible but `AttStatus` is shown wrong.

Comment: which where clause are you referring to?

Comment: You sure its not the inner join to the Att_Status_Master? The missing rows have NULL for status which would not pass the join criteria

Comment: @NathanSkerl I tried Left Join as well.

Comment: @bonCodigo I am referring to: where Convert(Varchar(25),dtAttendanceDate,112) = Convert(Varchar(25),tempStoredDate,112)

Comment: Check [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2f55/2) - it's simplified, but it clearly shows: with `INNER JOIN` you're "filtering out" the non-present data, with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, you get the data ...

Comment: @marc_s When date column is inserted, is it giving correct result? In the SQL Fiddle, you have not take date column of the CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move the condition in the WHERE clause to the LEFT JOIN

```
From TUI  
left join user_info UI on TUI.user_id = UI.user_id  
left join Att_Details AD on UI.user_id = AD.inUserId  
    and Convert(Varchar(25),AD.dtAttendanceDate,112)
       = Convert(Varchar(25),TUI.tempStoredDate,112) /* condition moved here */
join Att_Status_Master ASM
   on ASM.inAttendanceStatusId = AD.inAttendanceStatusId  
group by
   TUI.tempStoredDate, UI.user_id, UI.Display_Name,
   TUI.EmpCode, AD.dtAttendanceDate, AD.inAttendanceStatusId, ASM.AttStatus
```

Comment: See [WHERE Conditions on a LEFT JOIN](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN)

Comment: Still it is showing only those employees where dtAttendanceDate is present. Not showing all employees and all dates.

Comment: The last join is what turns the preceding left joins into inner joins (and thus eliminates the NULL rows). Did you perhaps mean to put it between `left join Att_Details AD` and `on UI.user_id = AD.inUserId`?